# COBOL 6.3 JSON-GENERATE SUPPRESS is suppressing all table occurrences

Tags: cobol

I am working with the COBOL Enterprise 6.3 JSON-GENERATE, using the `SUPPRESS` phrase.  I have the following COBOL data area:

```
05  contactInfo.                                   
    07  postalAddresses     OCCURS 0 TO 10         
                DEPENDING ON WIMBCST-POSTAL-COUNT.
        09  POSTAL-ID       PIC X(40).             
        09  addressCategory PIC X(30).             
        09  startDate       PIC X(10).             
        09  legalAddressStartDate  PIC X(10).      
        09  endDate         PIC X(10).             
        09  perpetualEndDate    PIC X(10).         
        09  perpetualStartDate  PIC X(10).         
        09  addressFormatName   PIC X(10).         
        09  POSTAL-SEQ          PIC 99.            
        09  postalAddressType   PIC X(20).         
        09  addressLines        OCCURS 10 TIMES.   
            11  addressLineType PIC X(20).         
            11  addressLineText PIC X(60).         
        09  locationLines       OCCURS 10 TIMES.   
            11  locationType    PIC X(20).         
            11  locationText    PIC X(60).
```

The data is initially LOW-VALUES.  When the JSON is generated, if any occurrence of `addressLines` or `locationLines` is eligible for suppression, the entire table is suppressed as follows:

```json
{
    "postalAddresses": [
        {
            "addressCategory": "Master",
            "addressFormatName": "US",
            "sequenceNumber": 1,
            "postalAddressType": "Unknown"
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though occurrence 1 of addressLines has data, and locationLines has 3 occurrences of data.

I am really expecting this:

```json
{
    "postalAddresses": [
        {
            "addressCategory": "Master",
            "addressFormatName": "US",
            "sequenceNumber": 1,
            "postalAddressType": "Unknown",
            "addressLines": [
                {
                    "addressLineType": "A",
                    "addressLineText": "123 MAIN"
                }
            ],
            "locationLines": [
                {
                    "locationType": "City",
                    "locationText": "TEST CITY"
                },
                {
                    "locationType": "State",
                    "locationText": "CA"
                },
                {
                    "locationType": "Postal Code",
                    "locationText": "99999"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any tips/advice on how I can use the `SUPPRESS` phrase and get the `addressLines` and `locationLines` items generated?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your JSON GENERATE statement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is a known problem that should be fixed by [APAR PH40288](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6485739)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: To expand my answer a bit more, I believe that this is a bug with the SUPPRESS phrase within the JSON GENERATE statement in Enterprise COBOL.  Unfortunately there is no known convenient work-around for the problem.  You may check the link to the APAR in my original answer for the status of the fix - as of now it is 'open' (meaning a fix for the bug is still in progress).  Hopefully one will be shipped soon! ;)

Comment: The fix is now listed as available.  Of course, I’ve written many lines of COBOL to get around this, but maybe we can get this installed in my shop.